# Sidekiq schedule same worker to queue when done

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am using Sidekiq with Rails 3, with the following worker class:

```
class BotWorker
   include Sidekiq::Worker

   def perform(user_id)
      user = User.find(user_id)
      puts user.email

      if condition # always true for now
           BotWorker.perform_in(1.hour, user_id) # not working
      end
   end
end
```

My controller simply has

```
BotWorker.perform_async(user_id)
```

However, on the Sidekiq dashboard, it doesn't seem like another worker is scheduled.

Also would like to note that the recurrence is conditional so it doesn't seem like I can use sidetiq or some sidekiq scheduling extension.

Still new to Sidekiq, read the documentation. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strange. I do the same thing except use `self.class` instead of `BotWorker` and it works.  I don't have any arguments for my `perform` method though.

You might want to wrap your method in a begin/rescue/ensure block and move the re-queuing into the ensure block.

If `User.find` fails to find a user, it's going to raise an error which Sidekiq will catch and should move your job into the Retry queue.  Probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for this. Finally got it working, turns out I had to rerun 'sidekiq'. Thanks

Comment: Quick question. You mentioned moving the requeueing into the ensure block.  But doesn't that mean if User.find fails, it'll retry?  I'd like to have Sidekiq not retry if User.find fails.

Comment: @DelosChang Yes, it would.  Sorry, if that's not your intention, don't put it there!  But you'll still want to catch any errors so Sidekiq doesn't swoop in and retry it for you.