# rails + sideqik... How to perform a task at a specific date and time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, cron, sidekiq, whenever

I am using https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq gem in a rails app to schedule tasks at a specific date and time..
Ex: Send appointment reminder 10minutes before the appointment schedule time.

```
class TextWorker
include Sidekiq::Worker

    def perform(appointer_id)
        number = Usermodel.find_by_id(appointer_id).contact
        Message.create(:from =>  email, 
                           :to =>   number,
                               :body => 'Thank you...Your appointment is at 10/1/2015 Sun, at 12pm')
    end

end
```

and calling it here in appointments controller:

```
class Appointments_controller

def create
    TextWorker.delay_until(10/20/2014, 13:40).perform_async(@user_contact)
end
```

delay_until doesn't work with specific date/time:

Is there any other way to perform a task at a specific date/time in sideqik? if so how? please

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894740/sidekiq-schedule-same-worker-to-queue-when-done) helps

Answer (score 5):

you could pass in the calculated difference in order to send what sidekiq expects

e.g. `DateTime.parse("10/20/2014")-DateTime.now`

so :

```
  delay_interval = DateTime.parse("10/20/2014")-DateTime.now
  TextWorker.delay_until(delay_interval).perform_async(@user_contact)
```

Comment: Running Sidekiq 5.1.3 I had to do `perform_at(delay_time, @user_contact)` instead of `delay_until`. Or `perform_in` instead of `delay_for` and pass a time interval.

Comment: @kaydanzie, are you running community version of Sidekiq 5.1.3 to perform perform_at(..., ..) ?