# Sidekiq Schedule a Worker for a Later Point in Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

We have an issue similar to this [Sidekiq schedule same worker to queue when done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894740/sidekiq-schedule-same-worker-to-queue-when-done)

The crux of the issue is that if more then one argument is passed to the `perform_in` it does not schedule them for later, but processes them as usual.

This works as expected, but is not useful because there are no arguments 
being passed into the new job

```
def perform(id, mode)
  begin
    Some::Process.remediate(App.find(id), mode)
  rescue CustomErrors::MyError => e
    # This will schedule a job, but without arguments :(
    self.class.perform_in(2.hours)
  end
end
```

This would be useful, but does not work as expected
The job completes and nothing is rescheduled

```
def perform(id, mode)
  begin
    Some::Process.remediate(App.find(id), mode)
  rescue CustomErrors::MyError => e
    # This does not schedule a job
    self.class.perform_in(2.hours, id, mode)
  end
end
```

Used:

```
Sidekiq 3.5.1
Rails 4.2.4
ruby 2.3.1p112
dev environment
```

Any help is highly appreciated

***UPDATE***

When the code is ran with a binding

```
binding.pry
self.class.perform_in(2.hours, 2, 12345)
```

It does schedule a job, but only on the first time. When it comes to it the second time around the job is being run for some reason.

Comment: are you sure you want to rescue that error and retry? why won't the error occur again? Why not just set `:retry` to true? Do you gain something from the 2 hour interval?

Comment: @toddmetheny Yes that rescue actually safeguards from the depleted api calls. This is just a simple example to illustrate. The time interval can be anything. In reality the number of calls is regenerated every hour.

Comment: Why don't you use a more recent version of Sidekiq?

Comment: @MuradYusufov tried that. Same result.

Comment: have you managed to figure this out? i too have having an issue with getting `perform_in` to run inside the worker